# Read data from webpage in Android

Tags: android, httpclient

I use this code for read data from html page and put in to webview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public WebView objwebview ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    objwebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
          try
          {
              HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
              String line;
              StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
              while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  str.append(line);
          }
              objwebview.loadData(str.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
          objwebview.loadData(e.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
      }
```

but when I run that ,I give this error ("android.os.networkonmainthreadexception") 
how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are accessing network connection in main thread. paste the following lines beneath setContentView(your_layout);

```
// Allow network access in the main thread
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: You cannot perform Network IO operations in the main thread unless you enforce it. By using the above two lines you allow your main thread to access the network and perform any network operation.

Comment: This is *not* a good solution.  In particular, even though it allows you to get rid of the exception, it will cripple your app's UI.  So it's essentially like turning off the safety guard.

Comment: Yes it will make the application hang for waiting response. But still helps in some exclusive cases. This one is informative. I'll upvote

Answer (score 3):

You are running your networking code on the *main thread* in Android.  Read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) to find some partial answers to your problem.

The basic idea is that if you perform synchronous reads that do not immediately return (i.e., things that take a long time, such as network operations), you need to do so on another thread, and then communicate the results back to the GUI.

You have a few options to do this: you can use an `AsyncTask`, which allows you to painlessly publish updates to the UI, or you can use a background `Service` along with an associated communication (either via AIDL or a simpler Message and Handler).